# Creating new column and insert value base on another column

Tags: vba, excel

I need help.

Currently I need to optimize the way i code and the process. Is there an alternative way for me to do this? The only way to differeniate the value is by the the first to digits. And there are hundred over values. As you can see in the codes, 99 will be assign value of 1042, 95 will be assign 261 and this goes on. How do I make it easier so that I have to input the values manually.Thanks in advance guys

```
Sub Netting()

 Dim Found As Range
 Dim LR As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim a As Variant, v As Variant

 Set ws = Sheets("PAYABLES - OUTFLOWS")

 Set Found = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Invoice amount", _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
 If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

 a = [{"HI99162152",1042;"HI99162159",1042;"99162161",1042;"HI95400159",261; "HI95400164", 261; "HI97500493",3004;"HI97500497", 3004 }] 'create 2-d lookup array

    LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 Found.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
 ws.Cells(1, Found.Column + 1).Value = "Netting"

    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("C2"), ws.Cells(LR, 3))
    v = Application.VLookup(cell.Value, a, 2, False)
    cell.EntireRow.Cells(Found.Column + 1).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "", v)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Mid(cell.value, 3,2)` to extract just the two digits and pass them to the lookup.

Comment: How do i implement that? Sorry I'm a total novice at VBA

Comment: From the code you posted that didn't seem to be the case...

Comment: Just edit your 2d array to include only the two-digit codes and their mapped values, and then look up the result of the Mid() against that.

Comment: I got help from multiple people just to reach there. Alright I'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: I'm getting error 1004. After this line,                                                       `code` v = Application.VLookup.Mid(cell.Value, 3, 2, False) `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Netting()

     Dim Found As Range
     Dim LR As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim cell As Range
     Dim a As Variant, v As Variant, num

     Set ws = Sheets("PAYABLES - OUTFLOWS")

     Set Found = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Invoice amount", _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     a = [{"99",1042;"95",261;"97",3004}] 'create 2-d lookup array

     LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
     Found.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
     ws.Cells(1, Found.Column + 1).Value = "Netting"

     For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("C2"), ws.Cells(LR, 3))
        num = Cstr(Mid(cell.Value, 3, 2))
        v = Application.VLookup(num, a, 2, False)
        cell.EntireRow.Cells(Found.Column + 1).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "", v)
     Next cell

End Sub
```

If there are a large number of values in your array then it might be easier to manage that as a table on a worksheet.

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot man. Really appreciate it! I have a question, if I want to change to look at the first two digits to the first three digit, what would I have to change? Just in case I need it in the future.

Comment: `num = Cstr(Mid(cell.Value, 3, 3))`